# Producing the Lucas series recusively using BigInteger in Java

Tags: java, recursion, biginteger, fibonacci

I'm trying to get the Lucas series into code using recursion and the `BigInteger` class, but I'm having trouble setting the base cases. This code correctly outputs the Fibonacci sequence, but everything I've tried to get the starting values, N(0) and N(1) to 2 and 1, respectively, have failed entirely. I've searched help files but nothing I've found has done it using `BigIntegers`, which I'll be needing as I do plan to go well above the `int` limit.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class LucasSeries {

    private static BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.valueOf(2);

    public static BigInteger fibonacci(BigInteger number) {
        if (number.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || number.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            return number;
        } else {
            return fibonacci(number.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).add(fibonacci(number.subtract(TWO))); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter <= 30; counter++) {
           System.out.printf("Lucas of %d is: %d%n", counter,
                fibonacci(BigInteger.valueOf(counter)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the applicable error code and message(s)

Comment: If I understand your question, this code works, but a bunch of other things you tried didn't work? What were those things? How did they not work?

Comment: Note that there's no need for the argument of `fibonacci` to be a `BigInteger`. An `int` will do fine unless you need to go beyond the 2147483647th fibonacci number, which is a bad idea. The return type can be a `BigInteger`.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I apologize for not being clear, but most of them were incorrect forms of what was presented below. I had attempted `return 2` as opposed to `return TWO` after separating BigInt zero and one in about three or four different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two base cases `N(0)` and `N(1)`. You *can* combine these, but the code more closely matches [the series definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) if you handle them separately, as in:

```
public static BigInteger fibonacci(BigInteger number) {
    if (number.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        return TWO;

    if(number.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
        return BigInteger.ONE;

    return fibonacci(number.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).add(
            fibonacci(number.subtract(TWO)));
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
Lucas of 0 is: 2
Lucas of 1 is: 1
Lucas of 2 is: 3
Lucas of 3 is: 4
Lucas of 4 is: 7
Lucas of 5 is: 11
Lucas of 6 is: 18
Lucas of 7 is: 29
Lucas of 8 is: 47
// Remainer omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if (number.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || number.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
    return number;
```

just return

```
if (number.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || number.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    return TWO.subtract(number);
```

that's all.

Comment: OP wants `0 => 2` and `1 => 1`. Not sure where you got this idea.

Comment: @AlexHall ok no problem, I fixed it, thanks for pointing it out.